# Primary screen flickering periodically

Tags: nvidia, display, asus

This is a weird bug I have been running into lately. When I connect the secondary monitor via HDMI cable, then after a period of some time the primary display flicker for a shorter period of time ~500ms and then get backs to the normal.

This interval is not exact as it changes after reboot <- this is the weird part

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

Comment: Not specific I can recall, just python related packages (using `apt`, not `pip`) for the project but they do not interfere with GPU or Display subsystem anyhow

Comment: Updated in the question @guiverc